# Application Insights missing browser info

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, monitoring, azure-application-insights

I added Application Insights to my web project using Application Insights button in Visual Studio 2017. After that I've added JavaScript code to `View\Shared\_Layout.cshtml` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-javascript)

After a week of monitoring I found that there is missing some information about client browser, OS, etc.

The following query returns only `client_Type` with `PC` value (but should also Mobile)

```
requests
 | project client_Type, client_Browser, client_Model, client_OS
```

Why it is empty? What I missed? Should I add some configuration to store that info?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right instrumentation key in the JavaScript bit in _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: @evilSnobu Of course, because other telemetry data I received

Answer (score 4):

**requests** *might not* have browser info.  that comes from the server side, so i want to say it gets everything from the `UserAgent` header of inbound requests.

*however*, the javascript code in your layout.cshtml enables **PageView** telemetry, which collects more information from the browser.

things to do:

1) make sure your backend (whatever is sending requests) is using the same ikey as whatever you have in your javascript snippet, to make sure you looking at the same data for both things

2) look at what's in both tables and see if it is different:

```
union requests, pageViews
| where timestamp > ago(14d)
| summarize count() by itemType, client_Browser
| render barchart
```

i bet you get a bar chart that has requests with one giant bar for one browser (empty), and a different bar for pageViews that has lots of browsers?